# how to solve post 404 when bot is deployed and used published url in endpoint?

Tags: c#, .net, bots, godaddy-api

[image]I have created bot locally, then I deployed it to GoDaddy, I get URL  http://abcddabot.abcd.com/
which I have used it into bot framework portal in endpoint https://abcddabot.abcd.com/api/messages
Used Microsoft Id Password and endpoint URL  https://abcddabot.abcd.com/api/messages in  bot code and published it with GoDaddy,
When putting https://abcddabot.abcd.com/api/messages, Microsoft id, password in bot emulator,
It shows Post 404 directline.postActivity 
How to solve it?

Comment: 404 means a client error and more specidically `Not Found` response from server. It seems you provide invalid authentication data to your post.

Comment: as i run locally on computer http://localhost:3979/api/messages, it work fine , bot respond , but when published that bot and used published url , microsoft id and password in bot framework url , it gives post 404 error, i used correct Published url ,microsoft id and password in bot framework, emulator and vs code

Comment: I am sorry we cannot help you, until you provide necessary info like `configurations`, `code` etc. -> https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: are you returning not found from api. its hard to tell without any code. is this .net core?

Comment: MicrosoftId:  0da30554-fe46-462b-b31a-983a2878b532,  hosted url on godadday:  http://echobot.masycoda.com/, I have used echo bot framework template from visual studio and put microsoft id and password in appsetting.json which is registered in bot framework , same id password  hosted url  in bot framework emulator, but it shows post 404